# Are there any plans for the JVM to support generics at runtime?

Tags: java, generics

You know, like the CLR does. Is anyone even admitting the lack of runtime generic information is a problem, and working to solve it?

Comment: @hvgotcodes: can't be used with primitives, no improved efficiency, can't use with reflection, inferior type-safety, and many, many corner-cases.

Comment: @hvgotcodes: It's not a big problem ordinarily in day-to-day development, but it certainly makes things difficult for certain types of libraries and such that really need to be able to get at such information at runtime. Take Guice, for example, which needs to work around the lack of type information with things like `TypeLiteral` and its subtyping tricks. There's other types of libraries that would benefit similarly.

Answer (score 4):

The designers of Java opted for this solution to maintain backward compatibility (on the bytecode level). Since then, there is even more Java code out there, thus breaking backward compatibility would have ever worse consequences. So I doubt they would change their minds about this.

Comment: They have mentioned that they'd like to do this in the future if possible, and aioobe mentions that there may be a way to do it without breaking backward compatibility so... I don't think it can be ruled out.

Comment: @ColinD, nothing can be ruled out of course :-) Note that @aioobe's quote proposes type reification as an _optional_ feature (supposedly for new code only).

Comment: @Peter the CLR didn't suffer any backwards compatibility issues when generics were implemented in .NET 2.0... what makes the JVM more problematic in this regard?

Comment: @Stephen, from what little I know about the CLR, there the same APIs are offered in both legacy and generic version; in Java (according to _Java Generics and Collecetions_) it was feared that this could lead to a versioning nightmare when many different APIs and libraries are involved.

Comment: @Peter, ah, I see. That's interesting, a colleague of mine with a PhD in computer science was commenting on how he thought having one type, for example List, which can be used both in its generic or non-generic form was confusing, and was intrigued when I told him .NET created a whole separate namespace for generic types (in fact, they had to, List<int> and List<string> are completely different types, for example... except they both implement the non-generic IEnumerable interface, one way .NET dealt with compatibility I suppose).

Comment: @Peter, in practice, I don't think the .NET community suffered from "versioning nightmares" due to the split legacy / generic APIs. When you encounter an API which uses non-generic classes, it's just a "shucks" moment. Whereas coming from .NET and working with Java for the past year I have experienced a whole lot of "WTF" moments when dealing with non-reified generics.

Comment: @Stephen, yes, it can be a problem in certain situations. And judging from the number of related questions on SO, it is quite confusing.

Answer (score 2):

> **Why is this a problem**  (from the comments to your question)

Well, consider for instance that can't overload a method like this:

```
void foo(List<String> strings) { ... }
void foo(List<Integer> ints) { ... }
```

even though it makes sense to actually allow this. (The main reason why this doesn't work today, is because it would, when compiled to bytecode, look like `foo(List strings)` and `foo(List ints)`.)

> **Are there any plans for the JVM to support generics at runtime?**

According to [this page](http://tech.puredanger.com/java7/) it's at least not in the pipe-line for Java 7:

> ***Reified Generics***
>
> *Currently, generics are implemented using erasure, which means that the generic type information is not available at runtime, which makes some kind of code hard to write. Generics were implemented this way to support backwards compatibility with older non-generic code. Reified generics would make the generic type information available at runtime, which would break legacy non-generic code. However, Neal Gafter has proposed making types reifiable only if specified, so as to not break backward compatibility.*

**Links**

- [Neal Gafter's blog: Reified Generics for Java](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/11/reified-generics-for-java.html)
- [Two problems with generics in Java](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/carcassi/archive/2010/04/09/two-problems-generics-java-0)

Answer (score 1):

I believe someone (possibly Mark Reinhold) said at JavaOne this year that they may try to reify generics in Java in the future. This certainly wouldn't be any sooner than Java 9 though, and would be a huge change with a lot of potential issues to be worked out.

Comment: It's 12 years ago yesterday when you wrote that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be *partially* solved without JVM changes: In Scala (running as well on the JVM) you can add so-called [Manifests](http://www.scala-blogs.org/2008/10/manifests-reified-types.html) which hold run-time type information for generic parameters. I think this solution could be adapted for Java without too much trouble. It isn't perfect, but probably much easier to implement as "the real thing".